# javascript: why no keys in the javascript objects

Tags: javascript, redux

Looking into [redux todomvc](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/actions/index.js), why no keys between the following `{}`? e.g. no keys before `text` and `id` in the following? A little confused.

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'

export const addTodo = text => ({ type: types.ADD_TODO, text })
export const deleteTodo = id => ({ type: types.DELETE_TODO, id })
export const editTodo = (id, text) => ({ type: types.EDIT_TODO, id, text })
export const completeTodo = id => ({ type: types.COMPLETE_TODO, id })
export const completeAll = () => ({ type: types.COMPLETE_ALL })
export const clearCompleted = () => ({ type: types.CLEAR_COMPLETED })
```

Any comments welcomed. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the answers and comments. I found my question is a little stupid. Currently, I am learning react and redux for fun. I am not familiar with es2015. sometimes, I cannot distinguish between 2015es new syntax and redux syntax. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Keys between what now?

Comment: He lost his keys.

Comment: That's ES6 shorthand syntax. `id` is the same as `id: id`.

Comment: *"I found my question is a little stupid"* Not at all, it looks really strange at first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In an ES2015 (and JSX) object initializer, you can create a property on an object by giving just the name of a variable without a value after it; the property's name will be the same as the variable's name, and the property's value will be the value of the variable:

```js
let one = 1;
let obj = {one};
console.log(obj.one); // 1
```

So on this line:

```
export const addTodo = text => ({ type: types.ADD_TODO, text })
```

it's not that the *key* (property name) isn't there, it's that the *value* isn't there (explicitly) for the `text` property. It's exactly as though it were written like this:

```
export const addTodo = text => ({ type: types.ADD_TODO, text: text })
// ---------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

It's just shorthand. But it's amazing how often it's useful.

Comment: It's a perfectly legitimate feature, but I still struggle with it because I'm so used to seeing key-value pairs in JSON. Too much mental gymnastics. :)

Comment: @user3608792 I think this feature, arrow function and object method shorthand syntax are the best features of ES2015.

Comment: how would you translate the arrow function in `export const addTodo = text => ({ type: types.ADD_TODO, text: text })` into "standard function"? because IE doesn't support arrow functions..

Comment: @SoulEeater - IE doesn't support JSX or modules either. Typically you have a transpiler like Babel involved to handle that (and a bundler to handle the module aspect). But since that arrow function doesn't use `this`, the traditional function version is `function addToDo(text) { return {type: types.ADD_TODO, text: text }; }`

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, is just that I had a completely different code but one part had the exact same structure on a function that I just couldn't make work on IE :)

Answer (score 10):

ES6 introduced a [shorthand for objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). In earlier implementations, we'd need to do something like this:

```
var id = "foo";

var obj = {
  id: id
}
```

But with ES6 we can simply do this:

```
var id = "foo";

var obj = { id };
```